# GraphQl filter in list field

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm working on GraphQL API, and I want to filter my data "Products" by sellerId knowing that a product can be sold by several sellers, which means the sellers' field is an array.

Here is the query:

```
query GetProducts($filterObject:ProductWhereInput!){
                products(where:$filterObject){
                    id
                    name
                    description
                    sku
                    price
                    sellers(where:$filterObject.sellers){
                        id
                        firstname
                        lastname
                    }
                    images{
                        url
                        fileName
   

         }
     }
  }
```

Filter variable is defined like that

```
{
"filter":{
    "sellerId":"ckzia0llkfngz0d09mrppd7kh"
}
```

}

and when I execute this query I get the error

```
"message": "unknown field 'filterObject.sellers' in variables"
```

I'm not sure if that's the correct method to apply the filter, it worked for me when I use it for single-value fields, but not with arrays.

If someone could help me, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Here you defined `$filterObject` as a query variable

```
query GetProducts($filterObject:ProductWhereInput!)
```

But the way this line is written, it "uses" a variable that is not defined:

```
sellers(where:$filterObject.sellers)
```

It's looking for a variable named: "`$filterObject.sellers`", not a property "sellers" of `$filterObject`.

#### Possible solution 1 - server side:

You can change the `sellers` field definition to use the whole `$filterObject` and then the resolver function on the server can extract the field it needs.

```
sellers(where:$filterObject)
```

This solution makes sense if you have control over the server side.

#### Possible solution 2 - client side:

If you cannot change the code on the server side, you can define a separate variable and use it instead:

```
query GetProducts($filterObject:ProductWhereInput!, $filterSellersObject:ProductSellersWhereInput!){
//...
    sellers(where:$filterSellersObject){
//...
```

(assuming `ProductSellersWhereInput` is a defined type)